# How to between 2 table join new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create new table.And I use 2 table join some area for the new table.How can write in sql query?

1.table--> Select ID,Name,Surname value and Insert Table 3.

2.table--> Select BranchCode,CountryCode,PersonUnit value and Insert Table 3.

1.table

```
| ID  | Name  | Surname | BranchCode | CountryCode  | PersonUnit
+-----+-------+---------+------------+--------------+----------
| 83  | Jeck  | Payl    |   150      |    087       |  154
| 65  | Alb   | Payl    |   130      |    983       |  965
```

Table 2

```
| ID  | Name  | Surname | BranchCode | CountryCode  | PersonUnit
+-----+-------+---------+------------+--------------+----------
| 83  | Jeck  | Payl   |   100       |    087       |  196
| 65  | Alb   | Payl   |   170       |    983       |  325
```

Create Table 3

```
| ID  | Name  | Surname | BranchCode | CountryCode  | PersonUnit
+-----+-------+---------+------------+--------------+----------
| 83  | Jeck  | Payl    |   100      |    087       |  196
| 65  | Alb   | Payl    |   170      |    983       |  325
```

Comment: It looks like you want to replace the values.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You probably want the merge function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `TEMP PERSON TABLE` has identical data to `PERSON TABLE`

In this case you do this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [TABLE TEMP PERSON];

INSERT INTO [TABLE TEMP PERSON] (ID,Name,Surname,Country Code,Telephone Code)
SELECT ID,Name,Surname,Country Code,Telephone Code
FROM [PERSON TABLE];
```

There is no updating happening here. Perhaps you need to update your sample data.

Comment: Yes an UPDATE query is certainly _another_ way to do it. You should post an answer. I feel the example posted in the question is incomplete anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below Query:

```
   UPDATE xp
    SET xp.[Country Code] = p.[Country Code], xp.[Telephone Code] = p.[Telephone Code]
    FROM #Person xp
    INNER JOIN Person p ON xp.ID = p.ID
```